# Using UNION in SQL with queries and subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the following code to try to UNION two sets of data,  although it runs without error, it is running for over 10 minutes and not returning results so Im wondering if there is something Ive done wrong?

```
select BIH.SourceCode, BIH.MarketValueAmt as CorrectedAmt
from [dbo].[IRA_HIST] as BIH
JOIN 
    (select accountno, accountclass
    from accounttable
    where accountclass in ('A','B','C','D')) AS AccountNos
ON BIH.ACCOUNTNO = ACCOUNTNOS.ACCOUNTNO
where BIH.securityno > '0'
UNION
SELECT SourceCode, (Amount*(-1)) as CorrectedAmt
from accttable a, activitytable b
where a.accountclass in ('A','B','C','D') 
and b.recordtype in ('r','c')
```

Any guidance is so helpful.

Comment: Look at the execution plan.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the permissions / access in my company to view them.

Comment: Then get it. No sense in debugging a query if you don't have the rights to do it.

Comment: Can you use `Union All` instead of `Union`.  That can improve performance (see [here](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/11/sql-server-difference-between-union-vs-union-all-optimal-performance-comparison/))

Comment: Change the JOIN in the second query. Don't use old style joins. May not be the issue, but wouldn't hurt to change it.

Comment: @WEI_DBA they are joined. It is an implicit cross join. This has been obfuscated so much with the table names it is hard to decipher what is really going on here.

Comment: Just a side note, you may want to post this on codereview.stackexchange.com for optimization help--though they will certainly ask for the execution plan as well. Good luck!

Comment: @SeanLange Agreed. Thanks. Why even have the 2 tables (same table aliased twice). Why not just have `Table a` and remove `Table b`. Confusing this one is.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I agree completely. I suspect in the actual query those are different tables. But this has been modified so much beyond the actual query that it lost all relevance and made this nearly impossible to answer.

Comment: Thanks for all your guys' help here, using the UNION ALL actually did a real number on improving my performance.  Apologies, I didnt realize removing the actual table names would make it so difficult to answer, seems the alias' would be enough.

Comment: @WEI_DBA when you say "old style join" what would you recommend changing it to, I did not realize that was an outdated way to join, always love learning new and better ways to optimize!

Comment: @SMBRADBE Using the syntax `from TABLE a JOIN TABLE b ON a.id = b.id`. It will read better also for others in the future. :-)

Comment: For joins...https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins And for aliases...https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Comment: When using UNION it will only return distinct rows which can cause some serious performance issues. UNION ALL returns all rows and doesn't look for duplicates, hence the performance increase. I suspect that second query could be greatly improved. As it sits right now it is a cross join and then removes a lot of the rows. Using a better join there would likely help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no other computations and transformations needed in data from accounttable, you can directly join it with ira_hist and no need to have the sub-query. Also, you need to have this ON a.[key column] = b.[key column] -- probably accountno on your join in your second query

```
SELECT BIH.SourceCode, 
       BIH.MarketValueAmt AS CorrectedAmt
  FROM [dbo].[IRA_HIST] BIH
  JOIN accounttable AccountNos
    ON BIH.ACCOUNTNO = ACCOUNTNOS.ACCOUNTNO
   AND BIH.securityno > '0'
   AND AccountNos.accountclass in ('A','B','C','D')
 UNION -- or UNION ALL if you want to retain duplicates
SELECT SourceCode, 
       (Amount*(-1)) as CorrectedAmt
  FROM accttable a, 
  JOIN activitytable b
    ON a.[key column] = b.[key column] -- probably accountno
   AND a.accountclass IN ('A','B','C','D') 
   AND b.recordtype IN ('r','c')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your 2nd **SELECT**, since you are querying the same table twice, you should be able to JOIN on a common key (e.g. `FROM TABLE a JOIN TABLE b ON a.cKey = b.cKey`).

Or, you could simplify that 2nd **SELECT**:

`FROM TABLE WHERE AccountClass IN ('A', 'B',...) OR RecordType IN ('r', 'c')`